# How do I resolve this recurring error when I run npm start?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, windows-10, expo, npm-start

I started with:

1. Installing Node.js on my Windows 10 System (I installed v12.18.3)
2. Then I ran command: npm i -g expo-cli
   to install expo on my system
3. Next I ran expo init demoProject
4. Next I changed directory into the demoProject (C:\Users\vridd>cd DoneWithIt)
5. Next I used command code . to start Visual Studio and in the terminal in VS Code, I ran npm start

As soon as I run this, I keep getting this issue. Please help!

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\vridd\DoneWithIt\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;;C:\Users\vridd\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\vridd\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Users\vridd\DoneWithIt
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\vridd\DoneWithIt
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by updating to the latest npm version (`npm install latest-version`) and doing an `npm update` on my project. From what I could tell from searching, it seems that some versions of Node and NPM don't play well together.